# How to iterate through all values in a dictionary when the key is a variable?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

```
students = {}
grade_collect = False
id_collect = True
while id_collect == True:

    ID = input(str('What is your student ID?'))
    students[ID] = {}
    students[ID]['Name'] = input(str('What is the student\'s name?'))

    decision = input('Would you like to enter another student? (y/n)')

    if decision == 'y':
        continue
    else:
        number = input('How many assignments were given?')
        id_collect = False
        grade_collect = True
        break

while grade_collect == True:
    for x in range(int(number)):
        x = input('Please enter the scores for ' + students[ID]['Name'])
    print(x)
```

I am trying to write a program that stores Student IDs, Names, grades, and scores that are inputted by the user; and eventually printing out the average scores for each student.

Because I have the keys for the dictionary as a variable 'ID' I cannot figure out how to get the program to prompt for the grades of more than one student; it just repeats itself.  In the first part of my code, I can get the dictionary to store all of the names and IDs, but when I need to go through the students by their IDs to ask the user what the grades on each assignment are, it only asks the most recent student ID in the dictionary.

I hope this is clear, thanks for any help.

Edit for clarification: By 'when the key is a variable' I meant that the variable ID is the key to each value.

ex.

```
{'1245': {'Name': 'Connor'}, '6789': {'Name': 'Josh'}}
```

The IDs aren't hard-coded, they are user input so they are a variable in the code itself. That is the part that is confusing me. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Put the second while loop inside the first one?

Comment: Just looking at the title - It does not matter if the key is a variable. You can iterate over the values as you do normally.

Comment: If "the key" is a variable, what does "iterate through all the values" mean? The values in a dictionary are not all associated with a single key.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already created a dictionary of students ID, you technically do not need another `while` loop. You can simply do the following to grab each users score.

```py
for id in students:
    score = input("Please enter the scores for " + students[id]["Name"])
    students[id]["Score"] = score
```

If there are multiple assignments, then another `while-loop` would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over all IDs using:

```
for id in students:
    #now in each iteration, 'id' points to one of the IDs in the keys
    #whatever you want to do with students[id]...
```

Comment: The question title is to "iterate through all values", not keys. It is not clear exactly what "when the key is a variable" means, so I would wait until the question is clarified before answering. It's also quite likely to be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @kaya3 OP clearly says "I need to go through the students by their IDs"..

Comment: OP also clearly says "iterate through all values", and your loop doesn't use the id for anything other than accessing the value. The loop also does nothing with the user input other than print out the last one of them, so it's definitely not clear what the OP actually wants.

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
for s in list(students):
    students[s]
```

Edited to better address the question.

Comment: The question title is to "iterate through all values", not keys. It is not clear exactly what "when the key is a variable" means, so I would wait until the question is clarified before answering. It's also quite likely to be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Also, but unrelated: `list(students.keys())` is the same as `list(students)`